# Find Specified Software - Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to check in AD if AV is installed via PS. If I run the script below individually, it comes out correctly where it is installed and where it is not.

```
if ( [bool](Get-Process 'Sophos UI' -EA SilentlyContinue) ) {
        $resultado="Instalado"
    } else {
        $resultado="Nao nstalado"
      }
return $resultado
```

However, when taking it to AD, the script below shows everything as INSTALLED, even on machines where it is not. How to fix this error?

```
function verificaSophos {
    if ( [bool](Get-Process 'Sophos UI' -EA SilentlyContinue) ) {
        $resultado="Instalado"
    } else {
        $resultado="Nao nstalado"
      }
  return $resultado
}

$Comps= Get-ADComputer -Filter {(Enabled -eq $True)} -properties *
$CompList = foreach ($Comp in $Comps) {
        [PSCustomObject] @{                    
        Name = $Comp.Name
        VerificaInstalacaoSophos = verificaSophos $Comp
        DataColeta = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    }
    }

$CompList | Export-CSV c:\temp\sophos.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

I want that the script shows correctly information.

Comment: Your code is constantly checking **your** computer if Sophos AV is installed or not since your function does not remote to the other computers. As aside, remove `-properties *` because in this case you only want the computer name which is a default property returned by Get-ADComputer

Comment: `invoke-command computer1,computer2,computer3 { get-package *sophos* }`

Comment: PowerShell is not PostScript, removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your function to accept a computer name like below and use that to invoke the command on the specified machine like:

```
function verificaSophos {
    param (
        [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )
    $resultado = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
                    [bool](Get-Process 'Sophos UI' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
                 }
    if ($resultado) { 'Instalado' } else { 'Nao instalado' }
}

$Comps    = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Enabled -eq $true'
$CompList = foreach ($Comp in $Comps) {
    [PSCustomObject] @{                    
        Name = $Comp.Name
        VerificaInstalacaoSophos = verificaSophos $Comp.Name
        DataColeta = Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    }
}
```

However, the [answer by js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78220294) is probably the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

`Get-Process` in Windows PowerShell 5.1 has a [`-ComputerName` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-5.1#-computername), the protocol used is DCOM, assuming you can connect to these hosts via DCOM then you can use:

```bash
$Comps = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True'
$map = Get-Process 'Sophos UI' -ComputerName $Comps.Name -EA SilentlyContinue |
    Group-Object MachineName -AsHashTable -NoElement

$Comps | ForEach-Object {
    $installed = 'Nao nstalado'
    if ($map.ContainsKey($_.Name)) {
        $installed = 'Instalado'
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name                     = $_.Name
        VerificaInstalacaoSophos = $installed
        DataColeta               = Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
    }
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\sophos.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Otherwise, assuming [WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/08-powershell-remoting?view=powershell-7.4) is enabled in these hosts and you have permissions, you can use a similar approach but with `Get-CimInstance`:

```bash
$Comps = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Enabled -eq $True'
$map = Get-CimInstance win32_process -Filter "Name LIKE 'Sophos UI%'" -ComputerName $Comps.Name -EA SilentlyContinue |
    Group-Object PSComputerName -AsHashTable -NoElement

$Comps | ForEach-Object {
    $installed = 'Nao nstalado'
    if ($map.ContainsKey($_.Name)) {
        $installed = 'Instalado'
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name                     = $_.Name
        VerificaInstalacaoSophos = $installed
        DataColeta               = Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
    }
} | Export-Csv c:\temp\sophos.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way over remote powershell.  Run get-package locally first to load the format file with the table view.  You don't need wildcards if you have the exact software name.  This runs in parallel.

```
$comps = echo computer1,computer2,computer3
invoke-command $comps { get-package *sophos* }
```